# Inserting JPEG or similar into ArcGIS map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, imagery, layouts

I am trying to upload an image (jpeg or similar) into a map.  It can be on the layout view or data view.  I am using ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: What is the function for the image you are adding (e.g. needs to be georeferenced for geospatial interpretation or is just a image graphic within the layout?)?

Answer (score 4):

On the top menu bar of ArcMap in the Layout View, click the **Insert** menu, and then click **Picture.** The properties dialog for the picture element will give you a number of [options](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Working_with_graphic_elements_neatlines_pictures_and_objects/00s900000022000000/), including a useful option called "Save Image as Part of Document" which stores the image as part of the map document:

[image]

Best Luck with this.

Comment: Note, however, that the image won't be georeferenced, if that's necessary. You'd have to use the georeferencing tools for that. If you don't care about that, no additional work needed.